# javascript library for comparing objects

Tags: javascript, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)
>   [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Are there any javascript libraries that can help with comparing two objects for equivalence? So if I have something like

```
var obj1 = {"name":"Jeff", "gender":"M", "arrayprop":[1,2,3] };
var obj2 = {"name":"Jeff", "gender":"M", "arrayprop":[1,2,3] };
```

And I would like obj1 and obj2 to return "equal" since they have the same properties/values.

Obviously `obj1 === obj2` returns `false`, but I didn't know if there was a function already available I could use that would return true.

Comment: Voted down. Question has been asked repeatedly (see comments above)

Comment: This was specifically asking if there are any libraries that help with it

Comment: (Revised) True, but it really is a fine line.  The answer you accepted was mentioned in 2/3 of the possible duplicates listed above and all 3 had answers based on library solutions. This was my first down vote; I seriously try to avoid them. In this case, looking at your stats I would've expected a search beforehand. After seeing the question I did a quick Google search to find a library-less version. The first two potential duplicates were the top 2 results returned from Google

Comment: I did search (and found those questions), but I overlooked the underscore.js mentions. You are correct though, I should have read the search results more carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is Underscore.js with the function `isEqual()` : http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual